# Google Cromebook Suddenly can't log into Ubuntu after 1 year of working perfect

Tags: login

When trying to open Ubuntu via the Acer Chromebook terminal:

```
shell/return
Sudo startunity
```

I recieve the error code below:

```
crosh> shell
chronos@localhost / $ sudo startunity
Entering /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/trusty...

_XSERVTransmkdir: Owner of /tmp/.X11-unix should be set to root

X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-76-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux localhost 3.18.0-16036-g30f3f9ed6ff1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Oct 31 22:05:44 PDT 2017 x86_64
Kernel command line: cros_secure console= loglevel=7 init=/sbin/init cros_secure oops=panic panic=-1 root=/dev/dm-0 rootwait ro dm_verity.error_behavior=3 dm_verity.max_bios=-1 dm_verity.dev_wait=1 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 3584000 verity payload=PARTUUID=d23a5ef0-30bf-b44b-a80a-09aa702675f2/PARTNROFF=1 hashtree=PARTUUID=d23a5ef0-30bf-b44b-a80a-09aa702675f2/PARTNROFF=1 hashstart=3584000 alg=sha1 root_hexdigest=50d7a3c8a009e7784812cfbc346a69f5be2f72e1 salt=9e651f5b8fcfbde1ca79de9098da3dbe7ee7156319d7a6fca082147143c73832" noinitrd vt.global_cursor_default=0 kern_guid=d23a5ef0-30bf-b44b-a80a-09aa702675f2 add_efi_memmap boot=local noresume noswap i915.modeset=1 tpm_tis.force=1 tpm_tis.interrupts=0 nmi_watchdog=panic,lapic  
Build Date: 12 February 2015  02:49:29PM
xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting, (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational, (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown. (++) Log file: "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log", Time: Mon Nov 20 07:42:25 2017 (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension Present
Initializing built-in extension DRI3
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension XVideo
Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
Initializing built-in extension SELinux
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
Initializing built-in extension DRI2
Loading extension GLX
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "ReleaseDisplayOwnership" with signature "" on interface "org.chromium.LibCrosServiceInterface" doesn't exist

xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
Unable to set master 
(EE) Fatal server error: 
(EE) AddScreen/ScreenInit failed for driver 0 
(EE) 
(EE) Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support at http://wiki.x.org for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log" for additional information.
(EE) Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "TakeDisplayOwnership" with signature "" on interface "org.chromium.LibCrosServiceInterface" doesn't exist

(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
/usr/bin/xinit: giving up
/usr/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
/usr/bin/xinit: server error
Unmounting /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/trusty...
chronos@localhost / $
```

Comment: Could you add the exact laptop model and version of ubuntu?

Comment: Please click this [edit] or the one below your question to add the request information. Thank you.

Comment: Acer Chromebook OS is 62.0.3202.82 - can't get into Ubuntu to check the version.                                                                                                                           Error code: (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
/usr/bin/xinit: giving up
/usr/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
/usr/bin/xinit: server error
Unmounting /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/trusty...
chronos@localhost / $

Comment: Crouton-related issues are off topic here. Please ask over on [Unix.SE].